# Hashmap not empty tuple vavr

Tags: java, tuples, vavr

I'm reading a file, and extract from if some fields that I suppose to store in a tuple. (vavr tuples)

The hashmap does not store any elements. I think I have a problem with initialization that I don't seem to figure out
Hashmap is of `Java.util` and the tuple from `vavr`

```
Tuple3<HashMap<String, Integer>, HashMap<String, Integer>, List<Tuple2<String, String>>> tupleResourceActivity = traceRecursion
                .apply(f, Tuple.of( new HashMap<String, Integer>(),new HashMap<String, Integer>(),new LinkedList<Tuple2<String, String>>()));
```

The trace recursion function :

```
traceRecursion = (x, t) -> {
        if (x.hasNext()) {
            Tuple3<HashMap<String, Integer>, HashMap<String, Integer>, List<Tuple2<String, String>>> tx = evtRecursion
                    .apply(x.next().iterator(), t);
            return traceRecursion.apply(x, tx);
        } else {
            return t;
        }

    };
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Its hard to read the definition of `tupleResourceActivity`. Why you dont use a custom-class for it? And how do you read your file?

Comment: I'm readiing the file using a log.iterator(). Do you mean by a custom class, creating a triplet class and a pair class ?

Comment: Yeah, some in this way. You can give the fields names so you can see very nice what that fields stores.

Comment: I wanted to exploit the tuples existing definition thats why I didnt

Comment: And what are you reach which this "exploit"? Nothing but a hard readble code, that nobody wants to maintain. Easy code is much better than "hacks" - in a couple of months you dont know what your code is doing.

Comment: Okay ,I'll see what I can do about